# Interpretation of a negativ epc (Modification Indices with lavaan)

Tags: confirmatory-factor, lavaan

I developed a new survey (10 Items) and run a cfa with lavaan, but the fit isn't that good. To decide which Items I should delete or which error variances I should correlate, I looked at the modification indices (I know this way is not recommended) I looked at the MI and the epc, but I am not quite sure, how to interpret this in the right way. For example:

[image]

What does in this case the negative epc mean? Could I argue that a negative epc changes the model in the wrong direction and so I decide not to correlate the error variances? Or isn't that a problem? I know that it is better, to use epc only above 0,4, but I would like to understand first, if the negative epc is a problem or if I could ignore the minus.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated. It is preferable to add example as code block, not as an image.